# I'm confused on the notation. Is the following justified or inconsistent?

Tags: punctuation

I'm writing a bibliography with the following two entries (written so far as shown):

I. Early modern authors and editors of late antique texts:

> a. 16th-18th century editions of late antique writers 
> b. Primary
>   sources (16th – 19th centuries)

I'm aware that in general different style guides will have different notation concerning the dash and the hyphen. *The question here is whether the different notation here is justified within the same bibliography*.

I have done some google searches and found entries that correspond to both, e.g.
a. [16th-18th century music](https://amajormusic.co.uk/products/31-pieces-of-16th-18th-centuries-descant-rec)
b. [books of the 15th – 18th centuries](http://nlr.ru/eng/coll/rare/cyrillic.html)

As I see it, in the first case (the block text above) 16th-18th century is an adjective modifying 'editions' while the second one refers to primary sources spanning the 16th to 19th centuries -- thus the different notation. In any case I'm slightly confused and would welcome explanation/comment.

Comment: Nobody is going to get too worried over your two-part AB rule (at least, don't worry about anyone who is that hyper-prescriptivist). I personally like it – it's clear (but then so would AA and BB be), and I think looks better than AA or BB. I personally far prefer the short dash you use to the long one (en and em are probably the correct terms, but who's bothered as one font's en-dash is another one's minus sign ...?)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Thx. That puts my mind at rest somewhat.

Comment: I disagree. The "short dash" is a hyphen, and shouldn't be used; it's for forming compound words. The "long dash" is an en-dash, and should be used for linking like here (but without spaces); an "em-dash" is even longer. I'm at work, but I'll write an answer in due course.

Comment: Yes, the usual convention is to use an en-dash in ranges rather than a comma. I'm happy with no spaces in your premodifier usage. The em-dash is rare in the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don’t see how it’s clear. To me it’s anything but clear. Whether a range is part of an attributive modifier phrase does not to me make any difference as to which glyph should be used to indicate that it’s a range.

Comment: @ Janus Bahs Jacquet [filler to adjust end-break] _Which of_ a. 16th-18th century editions of late antique writers 
b. Primary sources (16th – 19th centuries) do you find hard to understand, dropping preconceptions about what the 'correct' punctuation is (and I'm pretty sure that answers to a previous question indicated that different style guides disagreed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to any stylistic choice is to remain consistent. As such, as when representing a date range, you should pick a stylistic device and stick to it in all instances—unless there is a very specific reason to deviate in a particular instance.

When it comes to date ranges, most style guides recommend using an en dash rather than hyphen. Also typically, this is closed—there is no space on either side of the dash. (Where the em dash would normally be used in the US, the UK would use an en dash *with* a space on either side—thereby distinguishing it from an en dash without spaces.)

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 6.78, says:

> The principal use of the en dash is to connect numbers and, less often, words. With continuing numbers—such as dates, times, and page numbers—it signifies *up to and including* (or *through*).

---

Given that, considering just the date range itself, you should likely pick one of the following styles (which I'm listing in order of what I'd say is most common to least common) and use it consistently.

En dash (closed):

> a. 16th–18th century editions of late antique writers
>   b. Primary sources (16th–19th centuries)

Hyphen:

> a. 16th-18th century editions of late antique writers
>   b. Primary sources (16th-19th centuries)

En dash (open):

> a. 16th – 18th century editions of late antique writers
>   b. Primary sources (16th – 19th centuries)

---

As for the adjectival modification in the first sentence, conventional styling might say to add a hyphen between the date range and *century*:

> a. 16th–18th-century editions of late antique writers

However, while hyphenation in a compound (barring adverbs ending in *-ly* or open-compound phrases) is never *wrong*, it can sometimes look awkward in a way that is more negative than the meaning the hyphenation is trying to clarify. In this case, it's doubtful that anyone would misunderstand the phrase if the hyphenation were removed.

I wouldn't say it's a problem if you don't use a hyphen between the date range and *century*.

---

In short, it's up to you how you want to punctuate the date range. The more common styling is with a closed en dash, but that doesn't mean you can't choose something else. However, it *is* a good idea to remain consistent and not mix your date-range punctuation from one sentence to the next.

Comment: I would actually very strongly advise against hyphenating the compound modifier in this case. Since it’s not only a compound modifier, but a suspended one as well, you’d really need two hyphens, the first of which would come immediately before an en dash (“16th-–18th-century” corresponding to “sixteenth- to eighteenth-century”), and I don’t think you’ll find anyone who’d rate that very highly on the clarity or aesthetics scale.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It can really only be *suspended* if you don't use the en dash at all (which is another way of representing a date range): *16th- to 18th-century editions*. I would argue that the use of the en dash turns it into a monolithic entity (albeit with the same meaning). There is no reason to suspend an initial hyphen because the entire thing only needs one hyphen.

Comment: I don’t see why the dash (which simply represents the word _to_) should make in non-suspended. It’s exactly the same structure as with the word, just presented differently orthographically. If it weren’t a range, but two distinct centuries and they were presented with a slash to mean ‘and/or’, it would remain suspended (“16th-/18th-century editions”), so I don’t see why it wouldn’t just because of the dash. The dash is just the reason no one in their right mind would use the hyphens to indicate the suspension and compounding.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I consider the en dash to turn the two dates into a kind of compound word; you treat it as a single unit. If you use *to* rather than an en dash, you could also choose the same kind of compound representation (or even consider each word individually) and still not use suspension: *16th-to-18th-century editions*.